# How to debug ES6 + JSX Javascript file in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug a code that contains ES6 and React syntax, but I'm  able only to debug ES6 using the following configuration:

Dependencies: `babel-cli`,`babel-preset-es2015`

`launch.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [

    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Smooth Debbug",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/<FilePath>",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/core-frontend/node_modules/.bin/babel-node",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
    }
  ],
}
```

But the file I want to debug contains JSX syntax. Here's a part of the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Trans } from '@lingui/macro';
import moment from 'moment';

// ...

export const weekdays = [
  {
    index: 0,
    weekday: (<Trans>Domingo</Trans>),
  },
  {
    index: 1,
    weekday: (<Trans>Segunda-Feira</Trans>),
  },
  {
    index: 2,
    weekday: (<Trans>Terça-Feira</Trans>),
  },
  {
    index: 3,
    weekday: (<Trans>Quarta-Feira</Trans>),
  },
  {
    index: 4,
    weekday: (<Trans>Quinta-Feira</Trans>),
  },
  {
    index: 5,
    weekday: (<Trans>Sexta-Feira</Trans>),
  },
  {
    index: 6,
    weekday: (<Trans>Sábado</Trans>),
  },
];

export const findWeekdayByIndex = (index) => {
  const weekdayObject = weekdays.find(weekday => weekday.index === index);
  return weekdayObject.weekday;
};
```

If I run the debugger, I get the following message:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:18663/522a5a8d-18d5-4f39-9863-dab4dbc53709
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
<pathToProject>/core-frontend/node_modules/babel-register/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:558
      throw err;
      ^
SyntaxError: <pathToProject>/core-frontend/src/utils/dateTimeHandlers.js: Unexpected token (16:14)
  14 |   {
  15 |     index: 0,
> 16 |     weekday: (<Trans>Domingo</Trans>),
     |               ^
  17 |   },
  18 |   {
  19 |     index: 1,
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (<pathToProject>/core-frontend/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4454:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (<pathToProject>/core-frontend/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1761:8)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (<pathToProject>/core-frontend/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3750:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (<pathToProject>/core-frontend/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3494:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (<pathToProject>/core-frontend/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3474:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (<pathToProject>/core-frontend/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3404:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (<pathToProject>/core-frontend/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3381:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (<pathToProject>/core-frontend/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3344:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (<pathToProject>/core-frontend/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3828:26)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (<pathToProject>/core-frontend/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3709:19)
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
SyntaxError: <pathToProject>/core-frontend/src/utils/dateTimeHandlers.js: Unexpected token (16:14)
index.js:4454
    at Parser.pp$5.raise (<pathToProject>/core-frontend/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4454:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (<pathToProject>/core-frontend/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:1761:8)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (<pathToProject>/core-frontend/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3750:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (<pathToProject>/core-frontend/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3494:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (<pathToProject>/core-frontend/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3474:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (<pathToProject>/core-frontend/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3404:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (<pathToProject>/core-frontend/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3381:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (<pathToProject>/core-frontend/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3344:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (<pathToProject>/core-frontend/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3828:26)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (<pathToProject>/core-frontend/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:3709:19)
```

How can I debbug the JSX syntax in my code?

If you need more details, feel free to ask me!

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/reactjs-tutorial#_debugging-react

Comment: @messerbill I tried to follow the tutorial, and when I run the project, it works great... But am I able debbug a file alone? Without running all the project? Edit: Thank you for the answer.

Comment: i don't think that this is possible at all, rather with every file...the file itself mostly has dependencies to other parts of the application which makes it not really possible to debug those type of files alone....but i may be wrong at this point

Comment: Well, this file serves only static functions to the system... All I import comes from `node_modules`. But now that you said it, I had some insights. I'll research, and if I find something useful, I'll reply here. Thank you again, @messerbill